# Need axis title labeled "δ13C (‰)" but with the 13 as a superscript

Tags: r

I'm having issues finding the right code to include a superscript in my axis title. I need the axis title labeled "δ13C (‰)" but with the 13 as a superscript on the letter C at the front of the letter.

`yaxis <- expression(""δ^13*C "(‰)")`

I have tried many combinations but above is the code I have right now and it is not working.

Comment: On my windows box, I can do `plot(1, ylab=expression(delta^13*C ~ "\U2030"))` - does that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, `?plotmath` has the incantations to get this to work. E.g.:

```
yaxis <- expression(delta^13*C ~ "\U2030")
plot(1, ylab=yaxis)
```

[image]

Most of this is self-explanatory (e.g. delta writes a `δ` in an expression), but for reference, the unicode character for the *per mille* character can be found in the Windows Character Map, and referenced with the `\U` notation:

```
"\U2030"
[1] "‰"
```